# What is the efficient way for reading large content of data in Java

Tags: java, csv

First of all I am new to the Java and I have needed some help for the following issue.

I have a Java list which contains millions of records. I want to export this data list as a CSV file. Following is the function that I wrote to read the data but it fails for millions of records. Could you please suggest any better way of doing this ?

```
 private String generateCsvData(List<Map<String, Object>> rows) {

    String output = reportService.getReportHeadder();

    for (Map row : rows) {  

        output += (Long) row.get("branchId")
                + ","
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv((String) row.get("branches"))
                + ","
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv((String) row
                        .get("categoryName"))
                + ","
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv((String) row.get("products"))
                + ","
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv((String) row.get("emails"))
                + ","
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv((String) row
                        .get("contactAddress"))
                + ","
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv((String) row
                        .get("contactDet")) + ","
                + StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv((String) row.get("url"))
                + "\n";

    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? Does it throw exception? What exception? By the way, where is reading? I see that you're converting some data to CSV format. I don't think it's reading.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I would suspect an OutOfMemoryError in this case...

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` is suppose??

Comment: @assylias I suspect it too. But I'd like to be sure. Without suspecting.

Comment: Yes it returns this exception (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.) , I increased the heap size but still fails.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks a lot for the suggestions. I just tried out the file writing method and it worked. Will have a look on the other ways later .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store everything in a String before writing to a file, what if you write line by line to the file as you produce them?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). It has very nice support for [reading and writing data to CSV files](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, easily and gladly.

If you intend to hold all the records in memory at once you've got a problem.  Your machine only has so much memory, and only a portion of it is allocated to the JVM.  When you fill it the game is up.  You already have the data in the `Map`.  You double your problem when you have to store its .csv representation at the same time.

One solution is to stream out one row at a time.  You can iterate over the `Map` and only store the data once.

Another solution might be to store all that data in a relational database table.  You can iterate over a `ResultSet` and stream the results out that way.  Now you've really cut down on your memory demands.

You mechanism for creating the rows is not good.  I'd prefer a `StringBuilder` over concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're creating a veeeery long string and then want to write it to file.

Moreover you're creating a new String every tiem you concatenate. In these case use `StringBuilder`

You have to sequentially write using streams. [basic io](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) a good point to start learning

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSV library such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

You can handle the file line-by-line -  read a line, then process it, then discard it again. That way, at most one line of the file is in memory.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you construct a string in a loop, don't concatenate Strings, but us a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as it usually performs better and doesn't trash your memory with a lot of intermediate strings.

However in this case, I'd suggest to not keep everything in memory, but instead write directly to file during processing. This will reduce the memory required. Look at the [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) or look for a library that already does what you need (eg [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a framework like Spring Batch, it chunks operation which helps theoretically write many!!!!!!! records